# Обращаться к параметрам базы данных

Tags: java, android, sqlite

Создал бд SQLite, хочу обратиться к параметрам
Если раньше я обрашался к ним примерно таким образом:

```
name.setText(product.getName());
```

То теперь, с помощью cursor'a я могу обратиться к значениям бд таким образом:

```
Сursor cursor = db.query("PRODUCTS",
new String[] {"NAME", "DESCRIPTION"},
null, null, null);
```

Но это работает, если я сам вносил значения в БД. А как быть если я эти значения получаю с API(через retrofit)? Как быть тогда в этом случае?

Comment: БД на сервере ?

Comment: Что-то очень не понятно где трудности. Если БД на сервере, то делайте запрос и вставляете полученные данные. Либо качайте все данные в локальную БД и потом уже делайте запрос и получайте cursor

Comment: @pavlofff не совсем возможно правильно выразился, обновил вопрос. Саму бд создал у себя в приложении.

Comment: @pavel163 данные получаю с API хочу их занести в локальную БД, чтоб потом работать с их данными потом.